# How can I add a contact to Blackberry web application using JavaScript (if possible)?

Tags: javascript, security, blackberry, numbers, contacts

I need to develop an application, which adds telephone numbers to existing or new contacts in Blackberry. The application is preferrably a web application. Is it possible to add and read contact information on Blacberry devices using JavaScript? If yes, a code sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean directly into the BlackBerry address book? I'm almost positive that's impossible and would be a gigantic security risk if they did allow it (which only furthers my belief that it's impossible). Generate and link to a vcard instead. Then you just need a link like "Click Here to add to address book" and the BB Browser handles the rest.